# Javascript Variable outside of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
1| <script type="text/javascript">
2|    function more() {
3|          $("#innerSub2").animate({ scrollTop: "+=240px" },1000);
4|          var count = 1;
5|          document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#c7c9e9";
6|          var count = count + 1;
7|          document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#6464c1";
8|        }
9|     </script>
```

Helo, I am pretty new to javascript. So sorry if this is a stupid question.
On the first click event the variable works as i need it to( line 5, count=1)(line 7, count=2)
But on second click event i need ( line 5, count=2)(line 7, count=3) but as you can see it resets to 1 with line 4.
So the question is, how can I declare | var count = 1; | outside of function more() so it won't reset my variable? or if there is any other way to do this..
Also if there is a way to stop variable count from exceeding 3, please share
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a variable outside your function, so it wont be erased, this way the scope of your variable will be global, having a lot of global variables is considered not to be a good practice you can learn more about scope and javascript/jquery basics in this book http://jqfundamentals.com/book/index.html#example-2.44

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var count = 1;
   function more() {
         $("#innerSub2").animate({ scrollTop: "+=240px" },1000);          
         document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#c7c9e9";
         count = count + 1; //removed the var word.
         document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#6464c1";
       }
</script>
```

Comment: It would probably be best to wrap the code in a self executing function to prevent global pollution.  Another alternative would be to define `move.count=1` instead of count, and just work of the already defined `more()` global variable .

Comment: Thanks!  I tried putting "var count = 1;" above function but inside the function I had "var count = count + 1;" that's why it wasn't working. taking out "var" did the trick. Thanks guys

Comment: I'm glad it worked!!! don't stop learning the book that I shared with you is really helpful for learning the basics please take a look and please mark this question a answered as the rules of the site says so http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask "This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (And if you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)"

Comment: A flag was raised on this answer from a user who does not yet have commenting privileges. It seems that your link has gone dead. Do you have a replacement, or can you at least [edit] your answer to include the *title* of the book?

Answer (score 2):

```
 var count = 1;
 function more(count) {
          $("#innerSub2").animate({ scrollTop: "+=240px" },1000);
          document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#c7c9e9";

          if(count < 3)
              count += 1;

          document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#6464c1";

          return count;
    }



   then you just call more(count) on some event.
```

Comment: just out of curiosity, why mix jquery and straight js? document.getElementById("dot"+count).style.color="#c7c9e9"; should just be $('#dot' + count).css('color', 'c7c9e9')

Answer (score 1):

Exactly how u wrote

```
  var count = 1;
  function more() {
          $("#innerSub2").animate({ scrollTop: "+=240px" },1000);
          document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#c7c9e9";
          count = (count>2)?3:(count+1);
          document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#6464c1";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the var is inside function, and you are setting it to = 1, it will always 'reset' to 1. What you need to do is:

```js
var count = 1;
function more(){
    //js stuff animate
    count = count+1;
    //other js css
    count = count+1;
    //another js color
}
```

This is using your structure. 
You want to stop counting after 3 but still the other js to work or js stop working also?
Lets make both as example. 3 but js still work:

```js
var count = 1;
function more(){
    //js stuff animate
    if(count<3){count = count+1;}
    //other js css
    if(count<3){count = count+1;}
    //another js color
}
```

if you want all stop working then:

```js
var count = 1;
function more(){
    if(count<3){
        //js stuff animate
        count = count+1;
        //other js css
        count = count+1;
        //another js color
    }
}
```

There are better form of presenting but i used your code structure so you could better understand.

If sometime you need to reset the count in the same page, since the var is outside rhe function, it is a global var so other functions can access / modify. For e.g.

```js
function resetCount(){
    count = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, to add to Syred's answer, you should put some error checking around the DOM object calls. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var count = 1;
   function more() {
         $("#innerSub2").animate({ scrollTop: "+=240px" },1000);
         if (document.getElementById("dot" + count) != null) {
             document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#c7c9e9";
             count = count + 1; //removed the var word. (could also use count++)
             if (document.getElementById("dot" + count) != null)
                 document.getElementById("dot" +count).style.color="#6464c1";
         }
   }
</script>
```

If I knew more about how you were using the function, I might make other recommendations on how to streamline and check for errors, but this should give you a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use ***const***.

```
var info=[0,1];

function addView(btnIndex, btn){
    const index=btnIndex;
    btn.on("click", function(d){
        console.log(info[index]);
    };

}
```